# Selecting Max Date Per Day For Selected ID

Tags: mysql, join

I currently have a table that contains data structured with multiple entries per day for any given id.

I need to select the max date per day, so as not to select hundreds of records.

I'm using this query right now, but it returns only one max date period per id in the database.

```
 SELECT a.*
 FROM turtle_locations a
 INNER JOIN
    (SELECT turtle_id, MAX(date) AS maxdate
    FROM turtle_locations
    GROUP BY turtle_id) groupedtt 
 ON a.turtle_id = groupedtt.turtle_id 
 AND a.date = groupedtt.maxdate
```

What I want is if a specific turtle has say 10 entries in one day, to only return the most recent entry for that day.

The table structure is very simple:
turtle_id, date, latitude, longitude

Each turtle has multiple records over time with multiple entries per day.  For example view the data below for one of the turtles

https://pastebin.com/jpQB2VKW

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: Please check the posted answer(s) and give feedback.

Comment: This is a faq. Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using 1 variant search as title & keywords for tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text. When you do have a non-duplicate code question to post please read & act on [mcve].

Comment: Hi. Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use a link/image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. And never give a diagram without a legend/key. Use edit functions to inline, not links, if you have the rep--make your post self-contained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In your Sub-select query ([Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html)), you will need to group by on the date as well, using [`Date()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function. This will give you max date value **per day and id**.

Try the following:

```
 SELECT a.*
 FROM turtle_locations AS a
 INNER JOIN
    (SELECT turtle_id, 
            DATE(`date`) AS day_date, 
            MAX(`date`) AS maxdate
    FROM turtle_locations 
    GROUP BY turtle_id, day_date) AS groupedtt 
 ON a.turtle_id = groupedtt.turtle_id 
 AND a.`date` = groupedtt.maxdate
```

## [DB Fiddle Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tcLNkiqV3MwceXoUWaqTXB/0)

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/861ab1/1

```
 SELECT a.*
 FROM turtle_locations a
 LEFT JOIN turtle_locations b
    ON a.turtle_id = b.turtle_id
    AND a.date < b.date
 WHERE b.turtle_id IS NULL
```